# Passing variable as tags to ansible roles does not work

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

I pass a variable ACTION to site.yml as below.

```
ansible-playbook -v -i  sslhost.txt -e "APP_NAME=ssl-perf ACTION=renewal, gen_cert"  site.yml
```

My site.yml has ansible role called "manager" to which i m passing ACTION variable as tags. See below.

```
more site.yml
- hosts: "{{APP_NAME}}"
  user: "{{USER}}"
  roles:
   - { role: manager, APPLICATION_NAME: "{{ APP_NAME }}", tags: [ '{{ ACTION }}' ]  }
```

The manager role's tasks/main.yml looks like this

```
more manager/tasks/main.yml
---
# tasks file for manager

- include: manager_pull.yml
  tags: renewal
- include: manager_gen.yml
  tags: gen_request
- include: manager_gencert.yml
  tags: gen_cert
- include: manager_push.yml
  tags: install
```

I was expecting only manager_pull.yml and manager_gencert.yml to be included in the roles but the output shows that all the include in the manager role gets included / invoked.

> My ansible version is: 2.1.0.0

Can you please explain why am i not able to pass ACTION variable as tags to ansible role ?

Alternatively can anyone also tell me if and how would it be possible to pass tags instead of ACTION variable to the site.yml and get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass in tags as parameters to roles inside your playbook.  What you are effectively doing here is adding another tag to your manager role (`renewal, gen_cert`).

Instead of defining your tags with variables use the `--tags` flag.

`ansible-playbook -v -i  sslhost.txt -e "APP_NAME=ssl-perf" --tags=renewal,gen_cert  site.yml`

Comment: I tried your command but it is still including all the YMLs in the manager/tasks/main.yml instead of the just the two. What more changes do i have to make to get this to work ? How can i pass -tags=renewal,gencert to the ansible role called manager/task/main.yml ?

Comment: Are you still adding tags with the `ACTION` variable to the manager role inside your playbook? Are there any tags attached to the tasks inside manager_pull.yml, manager_gen.yml, manager_gencert.yml, or manager_push.yml?

Comment: You are correct. Along with your suggested command I had to remove tag[] from site.yml to make it work. This is how the role looks like now inside the site.yml after the issue is resolved   - { role: manager, APPLICATION_NAME: "{{ APP_NAME }}"  }